# Not receiving event notifications from DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the the DocuSign Rest API v2 and am not receiving event notifications when posting a Composite Template to the envelope endpoint. Here's what my json request looks like:

```
{ 
    'accountId': '[ommitted]',
    'status': 'sent', 
    'emailSubject': 'XYZ Corp_MSA_Singapore-OU_0.1_2014099.pdf', 
    'compositeTemplates': [
    { 
        'InlineTemplates': [
         { 
             'Sequence': '1', 
             'Recipients': 
             { 
                 'Signers': [ 
                 { 
                     'Email': 'jeff@mattnibecker.com', 
                     'Name': 'Jeff Dunham', 
                     'RecipientID': '1', 
                     'defaultRecipient': 'true', 
                     'ClientUserID': '1' 
                 } 
                 ] 
             } 
         } 
         ], 
         'Document': { 
             'Name': 'XYZ Corp_MSA_Singapore-OU_0.1_2014099.pdf',
             'DocumentId': '1', 
             'transformPdfFields': 'true', 
             'fileExtension': '.pdf' 
         } 
     } 
     ], 
     'EventNotification': { 
         'EnvelopeEvents': [ 
             { 'envelopeEventStatusCode': 'sent' }, 
             { 'envelopeEventStatusCode': 'completed' }, 
             { 'envelopeEventStatusCode': 'delivered' }, 
             { 'envelopeEventStatusCode': 'declined' }, 
             { 'envelopeEventStatusCode': 'voided' } 
         ], 
         'includeDocuments': 'true', 
         'requireAcknowledgement': 'true', 
         'loggingEnabled': 'true', 
         'url': 'http://netsureportalv2public.visusdev.com/DocusignEventListener.svc/EnvelopeEvent' 
    } 
}
```

The api is successfully create the envelope and everything. I'm just not getting event notifications. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to include accountId

Answer (score 0):

First, is DocuSign Connect enabled for the account?  Log into the DocuSign web console, then navigate to **Preferences >> Features** -- ensure that the **DocuSign Connect** checkbox is enabled.

[image: DS Connect]

Once that setting is verified enabled, next step in troubleshooting is to determine whether or not DocuSign even attempted to send the notification -- the "Connect Logs" will provide this information.  To view the Connect Logs: log into the DocuSign web console, then navigate to **Preferences >> Connect >> Logs**:
  [image: Logs]

Clicking the "Logs" link will show you the log entries for the most recent 100 messages (notifications) that DocuSign attempted to send.  For example:

[image: Connect Logs]

In the list of log entries, do you see any entries that are related to the Envelope that the API request sent?

- If yes, that indicates that DocuSign did send the notification (as your API request specified), but no acknowledgement was received back from the listener endpoint. This likely indicates that your API request is fine, but there's a problem with your listener endpoint (i.e., it didn't receive and/or acknowledge the notification).  Click on the link for that log entry and read the ending portion of the log text. That text will indicate the outcome of the notification attempt (and should include some type of error message if the notification failed).  For example:
  [image: Error Msg]
- If you don't see any log entries related to the Envelope you sent via the API request, then this likely indicates a problem with your API request -- i.e., DocuSign never even attempted to send the notification.

Going through the troubleshooting steps that I've described above should at least let you know where to focus your attention as you attempt to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The DocuSign connect feature is and always has been active for my account, however when I navigate to the logs page I don't have any logs for the envelopes I've sent out.

Comment: Within DocuSign, have you created a "custom Connect Configuration"?  If so, you should navigate to that configuration's settings page (Preferences >> Connect >> [configurationName_link]) and make sure that the "Enable Logs" checkbox is checked there.

Comment: When I create the Custom Configuration does it have to have a "Url to Publish"? I want the event notifications to go to a different url endpoint depending on which environment the app is running on (e.g. Dev, Test, UAT)

Comment: If it requires you to enter a value for "Url to Publish" when creating the configuration, you can enter anything (for example: https://www.google.com) -- just make sure that the "Allow Envelope Publish" checkbox is UNCHECKED -- that disables the Custom Connect Configuration, but perhaps just having it exist (even if disabled) with the "Enable Log" checkbox checked will make it so that log entries are created whenever you create Envelopes via the API (with EventNotification info).  It's worth a try anyway.

Comment: @KimBrandl do I have to enable DocuSign connect option even when I am using only the eventNotification Webhooks not the Connect Webhooks.
Also by default the webhook sends a Xml Payload to the endpoint, 
will it sent a json payload if i set useSoapInterface to false in EventNotification configuration added while creating an envelop.